# Extract part of string from each column' rows

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a text file with > 20.000 lines, like this:

```
7   128550681   128550681   Intron:1:36:RETAINED-RETAINED;Transcript:NM_001135914.1;Gene:KCP:protein_coding 1   1   0   0
1   17718672    17718672    Intron:9:16:RETAINED-RETAINED;Transcript:NM_207421.4;Gene:PADI6:protein_coding  1   1   0   0
1   17718672    17718672    Intron:9:16:RETAINED-RETAINED;Transcript:NM_207421.4;Gene:PADI6:protein_coding  1   1   0   0
4   86035   86035   Exon:4:5:RETAINED;Transcript:NM_001286052.1;Gene:ZNF595:protein_coding  1   1   0   0
3   12942851    12942851    Intron:14:14:SKIPPED-ALTTENATIVE_3SS;Transcript:NM_001134382.2;Gene:IQSEC1:protein_coding   1   1   0   0
```

What I need is 4th column contain just Gene:genename, so the output be like that:

```
7   128550681   128550681   Gene:KCP    1   1   0   0
1   17718672    17718672    Gene:PADI6  1   1   0   0
1   17718672    17718672    Gene:PADI6  1   1   0   0
4   86035   86035   Gene:ZNF595 1   1   0   0
3   12942851    12942851    Gene:IQSEC1 1   1   0   0
```

*** The problem is `Gene:genename` not always in the same location when try to split by `:` or `;`**

I know very basic awk/sed like how to select specific column, how to grep rows that contain some pattern

Comment: Mostly but not always in the same location :( @steeldriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the following `awk` command:

```
awk '{sub(/^.*;/,"",$4); print}' input
```

This will remove everything in column 4 up to the last `;` which may not work for you (see steeldriver's comment).  In which case please update your question with clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` with only POSIX defined constructs,

```
awk 'match($4, /Gene:(.+)\:/){ $4=substr($4, RSTART, RLENGTH-1) }1' file
```

To make the output a bit more neatly aligned, pipe the output to `| column -t` which will tab separate your columns. If you are unsure of the position of `Gene:genename` in your line, change the `awk` to look for the pattern anywhere within the line and modify the 4th column with the required value. Changing to `$4` to `$0` (the whole line) should work just fine.

```
awk 'match($0, /Gene:(.+)\:/){ $4=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH-1) }1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pale 's#(?:\H+\h+){3}\K\H+#($F[3] =~ /(?:^|;)(Gene:[^:]+)/)[0]#e' input-file.txt
```

° in the case of no fixed location of gene in the fourth field, we can do as above.

° we zero in on the fourth field by means of regex `(?:\H+\h+){3}\K\H+` and promptly replace that with another regex used in the substitute portion of the `s///e` command.

Answer (score 0):

Treating column four as a list of strings delimited by either `;` or `:` and replacing the whole column with the string `Gene` and the following one (the gene name) by first splitting that field and then finding the bit we want:

```
$ awk -vOFS='\t' '{ split($4,a,"[;:]"); for (i in a) if (a[i]=="Gene") { $4 = a[i] ":" a[i+1]; break } } 1' file
7       128550681       128550681       Gene:KCP        1       1       0       0
1       17718672        17718672        Gene:PADI6      1       1       0       0
1       17718672        17718672        Gene:PADI6      1       1       0       0
4       86035   86035   Gene:ZNF595     1       1       0       0
3       12942851        12942851        Gene:IQSEC1     1       1       0       0
```

Comment: Make sure that the output matches with what is wanted. The ":protein_coding"s are extras.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Thanks, I didn't notice that the biotype wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl:**

```
perl -F'\h+' -lane '
    for ( $F[3] ) {
        my $a = index(";$_", ";Gene:"     );
        my $b = index(";$_", ":",    $a+6 );
        $_ = substr(";$_", $a+1, $b-$a-1);
    }
    print join "\t", @F;
' input-file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
7   128550681   128550681   Gene:KCP    1   1   0   0
1   17718672    17718672    Gene:PADI6  1   1   0   0
1   17718672    17718672    Gene:PADI6  1   1   0   0
4   86035   86035   Gene:ZNF595 1   1   0   0
3   12942851    12942851    Gene:IQSEC1 1   1   0   0
$   128550681   128550681   Gene:$$$    1   1   0   0
```

**Explanation:**

- `perl` options:

  - `-n` => invoke a line-by-line read of the input.
  - `-F` => will make `FS = horizontal whitespace`.
  - `-a` => split each line into fields (based on whatever FS was set by `-F` option or a single space by default) and store them in the array `@F`.
  - `-l` => will make `RS = ORS = "\n"`.
  - `-e` => what follows is to be treated as `Perl` code and applied on each line, a.ka., record.
- `data structures` involved:

  - `@F` => the array populated with the fields got by splitting the record. Indexed from 0. So `$F[3]` is the fourth field in the record.
  - `$a` => holds the position of the substring `;Gene:` in the 4th field.
  - `$b` => holds the position of the substring `:` in the 4th field, that is found looking 6 digits AFTER the position of `;Gene:`. IOW, it finds the second `:` after the `;Gene`. Note: We pad a semicolon to the search string, that is, `$F[3]`, since the position of `Gene:` can be anywhere, so it can very well be at the beginning of  he fourth field as well. This is to take care of that eventuality.
  - `$_` => holds the localized version of `$F[3]` inside a `for` loop. the `substr` builtin will extract the `gene:...` info and store it back in `$F[3]`.
  - Note: the `my` qualifier before the variable definitions for `$a,$b` mark them to be lexical variables whose scope is limited to the `for` loop only.
  - Note: `$_` inside the `for` loop does NOT refer to the current record/line. It has been overloaded and localized for the duration of the `for` loop to be `$F[3]`.

**GNU Sed:**

```
sed -Ee '
    s/\S+/\n&\n/4
    s/\n(.*;)?(Gene:[^:]+):.*\n/\2/
' input-file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- We mark out the fourth field with newlines.
- Having staked out the region in the current line, we then fish out the required data, in our case, `Gene:` and after that, `as many non colons we meet on the way before we hit the next colon`.
- This method does not disturb the spacing existing between the various fields. This may or may not be important.
- Note FYI: Assumes a single gene in  the fourth field. For multiple genes, it won't error out or warn, rather silently pick the last gene of the 4th field of that record.